# Prove the inequality $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \; d_{\ell^2}(x, y) \leq d_{\ell^1}(x, y)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Then $$d_{\ell^2} (x,y) \leq  d_{\ell^1} (x,y)$$
Which is to say $$(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - y_i)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - y_i|$$
If we square both sides, we get $$d_{\ell^1}(x,y)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - y_i)^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - y_i|)^2$$
$$ = (\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - y_i|)(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - y_i|)\quad (*)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - y_i|^2 + \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n; i\neq j} |x_i - y_i|\times |x_j - y_j| \quad (\clubsuit)$$
$$\geq \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - y_i|^2 = d_{\ell^2} (x,y)^2$$
I'm having trouble understanding how to go from line $(*)$ to $(\clubsuit)$. Any help?

Comment: Waht type of terms do you get when you carry out the multiplication in $(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - y_i|)(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i - y_i|)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, after squaring, you essentially want to argue that (calling $x_i-y_i=a_i$)

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n  a_i^2 \leq \Big( \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| \Big)^2. $$

Note $$\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| \Big)^2 =(a_1+a_2+\ldots a_n)(a_1+a_2+\ldots a_n)=  \sum_{ i=1 }^n |a_i|^2+\sum_{i,j=1, i \neq j}^n |a_i||a_j|,$$

where the above equality is just distributing the product. If you cant see it then imagine $n=2$ :
$$(a_1+a_2)(a_1+a_2)=\underbrace{a_1^2+a_2^2}_{i ~\text{terms}} +\underbrace{a_1a_2+a_2a_1}_{i\neq j ~\text{terms}}.$$